# How to run multiple scripts in remote machine

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, remote-access

I have to remotely connect to a gateway(working on Linux platform), inside which I have couple of executable files (signingModule.sh and taxModule.sh).
Now I want to write one script in my desktop which will connect to that gateway and run signingModule.sh and taxModule.sh in two different terminals.

I have written below code:

```
ssh root@10.138.77.150 #to connect to gateway

sleep 5

cd /opt/swfiscal/signingModule #path of both modules

./signingModule #executable.
```

But through this code I am able to connect my gateway but after connecting to gateway nothing is happening.

2nd code:

```
source configPath # file where i have given path of both the modules

cd $FCM_SCRIPTS # variable in which i have stored the path of modules

ssh root@10.138.77.150 'sh -' < startSigningModule** #to connect and run one module.
```

as an output of this i am getting:

> -source: configPath: file not found

Please help me working this out. Thanks in advance.

Notes:

1. I can copy paste my files in that gateway if required.
2. `Gnome-Terminal` or any other alternatives of this is not working in my gateway

Comment: You can do something like this. ssh bar@foo "command1 && command2"

Comment: its not working :(

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no..see to enter to that gateway i have to give one password..so as soon as i am giving that password after running this : **ssh root@10.138.77.150 "cd /opt/swfiscal/signingModule && ./signingModule"**, then nothing is happening

Comment: That's strange. Check whether at least this command is working for you. ssh root@10.138.77.150 "cd /opt && ls"

Comment: yes Asanka it is working

Comment: so what can be done now??

Comment: That means these two commands are wrong. cd /opt/swfiscal/signingModule   && ./signingModule. Please recheck your directory names script name etc.

Comment: I tried...manually in terminal these two are working perfectly fine..
first i gave
1. ssh root@10.138.77.150
2. cd /opt/swfiscal/signingModule && ./signingModule
this is working

Comment: i tried this also **ssh root@10.138.77.150 "cd /opt/swfiscal/signingModule && echo "hello" "** and it is working. i have no clue why ./signingModule is not working. however separatly ./signingModule is working..

Comment: can you show me the output of this command ssh root@10.138.77.150 "cd /opt/swfiscal/signingModule && ll "

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh root@10.138.77.150 "cd /opt/swfiscal/signingModule && ./signingModule"
```

Line `source configPath` doesn't work because you need specify full path to the file.

Comment: i will try this. but what if i want to run multiple file in different terminals

Answer (score 0):

You can pass several commands to ssh to run them in sequence; but I prefer a different solution: I have *whole* scripts locally; and running them remotely means:

1. Using **scp** to copy my script to the remote system
2. Using **ssh** to then run the script on the remote system

The big advantage here: there is always a potential for getting things wrong (for example: quoting) when directly giving commands to ssh. But when you put everything into a script, you have exact/full control over what is going to happen. You can put things like "set -e" into your script to improve error handling ...

(and of course, you can also automate the two steps listed above!)

Comment: sorry i really dont get this thing.. i am not that expert in bash scripting.. still learning.. it would be very helpful if you can explain me about this